What does the deployment in lambda stages actually do?
I have configured an api gateway with lambda function integrated and no automatic deployment. Then I configured two stages. If I change the lambda function and click on deploy in lambda, the just deployed function is executed.
But, when I change the stage variables in the api gateway, then they are also directly
So, what is the purpose of the deploy function in the api gateway, if everything stays allegitely the same?

in Api Gateway you integrate your lambda in a method under a resource of the API. In the integration request of this method, it points to a specific lambda and a specific version. If no version is indicated, it points to the latest deployed version, called version $LATEST. This is the reason why what you mention in your question happens.
If you point to a specific version in api gateway and deploy a new version in Lambda, api gw it would still point to a static version and not the latest one.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-versions.html

so deploying means basically putting a certain alias to the latest version? If so, why would this make sense?

To the version that you indicate in the integration with api gateway, not always the latest... If you have api gw in version 11 (not latest) and lambda deploys to 14.. deploy in api don't change anything for this method. Also, think that api gw may have hundreds of resources, methods and different integrations (lambda, app runner, ecs, ec2, etc...)

But with lambda and stages, you would use stage variables and not a specific version. This would be defined by the stage variable. So, please, explain me the purpose.
